# Assembling namespace name + container based on preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Tried couple of variants of below code but doesn't compile, basically what I want to achieve is that I want to be able to define namespace i.e. std or eastl and then simply append it to container type:

```
#ifndef EASTL 
#include <vector> 
#define NMS std  
#else  
#include <EASTL\vector.h>
#define NMS eastl  
#endif

template<class T>
using vector_t = NMS##::##vector<T>;
```

But unfortunately I wasn't able to find a way to do it. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: This is not a typographical error...

Answer (score 1):

If you're really sure you want that, simply put

```
#ifndef EASTL 
#include <vector> 
#define NMS std  
#else  
#include <EASTL\vector.h>
#define NMS eastl  
#endif

template<class T>
using vector_t = NMS::vector<T>;
```

without the `##` preprocessor directives (those are only handled within macro definitions, not in templates).